# Python 3 - Как просканировать папку /tmp, найти в ней файлы, которые начинаются с "x" и удалить их?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Я делаю программу для очистки кеша / мусора.
Она будет удалять всё, что начинается с:

```bsh
1) Папки ".com.google.Chrome."
2) Файлы "config-err"
3) Папка "mintUpdate"
4) Файлы-изображения "xapp-tmp-"
5) Папки "ssh-"
```

Давайте код только для Linux, у меня нет Windows.

Comment: и что вы уже сделали? что не получилось?

Comment: Я не знаю как сделать, как раз пытаюсь найти ответ. Но его нет

Comment: на что нет ответа - как получить список файлов в папке? гугл в помощь - миллион страниц. выбирайте и пробуйте

Comment: @splash58 ответа нет на то, почему за него это никто еще не сделал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых **ВСЕ** нужные функции доступны для поиска в интернете.

Вот код:

```
import os

tmp_path='/tmp'

os.chdir(tmp_path) # Переходим в tmp
all_dirs_and_files = os.listdir() # Получаем список файлов
patterns = ['.com.goole.Chrome.', 'config-err', 'mintUpdate', 'xapp-tmp-', 'ssh-'] # Здесь список проверяемых паттернов
for f_or_d in all_dirs_and_files: # Перебираем все папки и файлы
    flag = False
    for patt in patterns:
        if f_or_d.startswith(patt): # Проверяем на соответствие с каждым паттерном
            flag = True
    if flag: # Если подошло под паттерн
        if os.path.isfile(f_or_d): # Проверяем файл ли это
            os.remove(f_or_d) # Удаляем файл
        else:
            os.rmdir(f_or_dir) # Иначе удаляем папку
```

**Прочти некоторые списки полезных функций:**

[Про методы строк](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html)

[Про модуль os](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os.html)

[Про проверку является ли это файлом или директорией](https://tonais.ru/file/kak-proverit-yavlyaetsya-put-faylom-katalogom-python#:%7E:text=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9,%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC.%20%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%86%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

## UPDATE

Сразу не заметил что некоторые паттерны под папки, некоторые только под файлы.

Вот улучшенный код

```
import os

tmp_path='/tmp'

os.chdir(tmp_path) # Переходим в tmp
all_dirs_and_files = os.listdir() # Получаем список файлов
patts_d = ['.com.goole.Chrome.', 'mintUpdate', 'ssh-'] # Здесь список проверяемых паттернов для директорий
patts_f = ['config-err', 'xapp-tmp-']
for f_or_d in all_dirs_and_files: # Перебираем все папки и файлы
    if os.path.isfile(f_or_d): # Проверяем файл ли это
        flag = False
        for patt in patts_f:
            if f_or_d.startswith(patt): # Проверяем на соответствие с каждым паттерном
                 flag = True
        if flag: os.remove(f_or_d)
    else:
        flag = False
        for patt in patts_d:
            if f_or_d.startswith(patt): # Проверяем на соответствие с каждым паттерном
                 flag = True
        if flag: os.rmdir(f_or_d)
```

Comment: Это работает. Благодарю!

Comment: У вас проверка и удаление не атомарно, поэтому скрипт с интересными багами. Иными словами код так себе, работает по счастливому стечению обстоятельств.

Comment: @0andriy, плохо понимаю, в чем эти интересные баги, не могли бы вы объяснить

Comment: Между проверкой на "каталог или файл" и "удаляем файл (каталог)" может произойти смена типа файла на всё, что угодно. Соответственно ваш вызов `os.rmdir()`, например, может крэшнуть программу. Типичная ошибка вида "race condition".